# Trying to add multiple images in an object

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-native, object

I have a form object that holds all my input values.  I am working with the react-native camera component and what I am trying to accomplish is every time a picture is added, it is added to the object. With my current code, I am getting invalid attempts to spread non-iterable instances.

```
import { TicketContext } from "../store/TicketContext";

function Pictures() {
  const [hasCameraPermissions, setHasCameraPermissions] = useState();
  const [picture, setPicture] = useState();
  const { form, setForm } = useContext(TicketContext);

  //Add picture to form //
  const handleAddPicture = () => {
    setForm([...(form ?? []), { picture: picture.uri }]);
    setPicture();
  };

  const cameraRef = useRef();

  //Get Permission to use Camera//
  const handleCameraPermissions = async () => {
    const cameraPermissions = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
    setHasCameraPermissions(cameraPermissions.status === "granted");
  };

  // Check for permissions on load //
  useEffect(() => {
    handleCameraPermissions();
  }, []);

  if (hasCameraPermissions === undefined) {
    return <Text>Permissions Required...</Text>;
  } else if (!hasCameraPermissions) {
    return <Text>Camera Permission Denied. Please change in settings.</Text>;
  }

  //Take Picture //
  const handleTakePicture = async () => {
    const options = { base64: true, exif: false, quality: 1 };
    const newPicture = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync(options);
    setPicture(newPicture);
  };

  if (picture) {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          style={styles.preview}
          source={{ uri: "data:image/jpg;base64," + picture.base64 }}
        />
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button title="Add Picture" onPress={handleAddPicture} />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Camera style={styles.cameraContainer} ref={cameraRef}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button title="Take Picture" onPress={handleTakePicture} />
        </View>
      </Camera>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default Pictures;
```

setPicture returns the state back to undefined

my state in context

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({});
```

Comment: How does the `prevState` look before that operation?

Comment: is your prevState an iterator, or an object holding an iterator? It looks like you want the new state to be an array, so I think it s a logic problem on your part :)

Comment: I wish I knew the answer to iterator or object holding an iterator.  I do want it to be an array, but I can't wrap my head around how to do it.  I need to get back to studying more

Answer (score 0):

```js
//[form ,setForm]
// make sure you object keys are camel case. 
const handleAddPicture = () => {
setForm([...(form ?? []), { picture: picture.uri }]);
setPicture();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.. I tried this out, but for some reason I still am getting the invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.   You are right about the camelcase.  I need to fix a bunch of my keys

Comment: please show more code, i want to see more of your flow and you state model.

Comment: question updated

Comment: why are you setting the context this way ?

Comment: your context must be local if you want to update the global context then use dispatch function from your component

Comment: I have multiple components throughout the app that use the [form, setForm] to update the object. As you can tell, I am pretty new, but all seems to be working correctly.  I just can't seem to add these images from the camera.  I hope that made sense

Comment: is the picture value ture ? I mean check it by console.log(newPicture) !! and see what is in there .. could be a flow issue from the start, if you are saying that the form works fine in other places.

Comment: Yea, newPicture is returning a uri and base64. I'm able to add the uri but it's when I want to add more than one, it gets over written.  I need to figure out how to create an array

Comment: its normal behaved for it to be over written so it is getting in to state form ?? your isssue is that is getting over writee ?

Comment: your form is an object btw {} why is that ? make it [form, setFrom ] = useState([/* data*/]) ditch the object !!!

Comment: const [form, setForm] = useState({}); you form default state must be an array   useState([])  !!! then my answer will work for you ! this is an array [] this is an object {} !!!